# Setup notifications for changes in user timeZone

Tags: office365

As per the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks here it mentioned supported resources. But I need to listen the changes in mailboxSettings (With this I'm getting user timezone).

Is it possible to listen for mailboxSettings resource.